# How to configure SCons to use a specific MSVC install

Tags: scons, msvc12

We have just starting to use conan as an package manager and SCons as construction tool. One of the package that I have download as package is also MSVC. So, MSVC is now locally available in project folder. The question is how reference the local folder/compiler to the SCons construction tool? What should be the syntax in sconstruct?

One example what does not work is here:

```
import os

# compiler path
path = ['D:/Git/project/08_tools/pcks/MSVC_13_10_3052/bin/']
# new environment instance
e = Environment(tools = ['msvc'], ENV = {'PATH' : path})
```

This is only a basic example. I don't know where to put in the MSVC local path that will work? I have also install Visual Studio with actual MSVC compiler and have worked with same example.

Comment: I am missing quite some information. I'd suggest submitting a ticket to Github issues in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues and provide: a more complete ``conanfile.py``, the exact command you are running, details about the Conan version, OS, compiler, the full output of the command, etc.

Comment: SCons does have construction variables that let you specify tool versions, but since there are a ton of possible combinations over time from Microsoft, it's not completely trivial to figure out exactly what you need.  A lot of the extra choices were added quite recently. You could start here https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#cv-MSVC_NOTFOUND_POLICY and scroll down and see what makes sense for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring MSVC for use is unfortunately more complicated than just adding it to your path. (MSVC's setup script set LINK, PATH, and other shell variables which are used when building/linking/etc with MSVC)

Likely the best solution for you is something like this:

```
# compiler path
path = ['D:/Git/project/08_tools/pcks/MSVC_13_10_3052/bin/']
msvc_script='D:/Git/project/08_tools/pcks/MSVC_13_10_3052/path_to../vcvars.bat'
# new environment instance
e = Environment(tools = ['msvc','mslink','mslib'], MSVC_USE_SCRIPT=msvc_script)
```

You can see more info on the MSVC_USE_SCRIPT in the [manpage](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html#cv-MSVC_USE_SCRIPT).